# Treeview ExpanderButton Always Visible?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, treeview, expander

### Problem

I have a Silverlight 5 application using the treeview from the SDK. Now by using databinding, mvvm, and `HierarchicalDataTemplate` I've created lazy loading for each of the items in the treeview. Now the `ExpanderButton` is ofcourse only visible if it has items. Is there a way so I can always show this `ExpanderButton`. I do know I have to edit the style template for this to work. But I'm not sure what to edit.

### Goal

Always Show the ExpanderButton for a TreeViewItem. (Possibly with logic added to it. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="HasItemsStates">
 <VisualState x:Name="HasItems" />
 <VisualState x:Name="NoItems">
  <Storyboard>
   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ExpanderButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
      <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
     </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Did the job